# How we select radio button in user input form using selenium webdriver and python. In this user in inputting all details in console

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

**When user automate the webpage account creation form it contain radio button male and female.**
When user input male and script is run it should select male and for female selection radio button of female should be selected.

Comment: if sex == 1:
    driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_9").sendkeys(sex)
elif sex ==2:
    driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_a").sendkeys(sex)
else:
    print('I am sorry')

Comment: Below is the snippet of code.

Comment: Post the HTML of the relevant radio buttons. Also edit your question and add the details from your comments so future readers don't miss the details you added later.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rohitgupta/Facebook_Account_Creation.

Automation of Facebook Account Creation with Selenium Webdriver with Python. 
In this we have automated the process of Account creation.